# .NET Standard - Merge a certificate and a private key into a .pfx file programmatically

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, .net-standard

Is there any way to combine a certificate and a key (both received separately as Base64 strings from a service) into a .pfx file using C#/.NET Standard **programmatically**? Using a tool is not an option, since I need to automate it.

The context: I need to load a certificate and a private key (separate Base64 strings without headers and footers) to a `X509Certificate2` object to pass it on to the app from a .NET Standard 1.6 library. 
The problem is, there is no `PrivateKey` property in the `X509Certificate2` class in .NET Standard! So the only way for me to actually load the private key in a `X509Certificate2` object is to combine it with the certificate itself in a .pfx file and load it like that in a constructor.

Answer (score 16):

There's not a way to do this with framework types.  It may be possible with BouncyCastle, or other libraries.

.NET Core 2.0 has added the ability to merge a certificate and a key object together (into a new X509Certificate2 object) via extension methods:

```
X509Certificate2 mergedCert = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaPrivateKey);
X509Certificate2 mergedCert = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(dsaPrivateKey);
X509Certificate2 mergedCert = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(ecdsaPrivateKey);
```

But that requires compiling specifically for netcoreapp20 (not netstandard20).

The framework types also don't have a way of loading key objects from binary representations (with the exception of `CngKey.Import`, but that only works on Windows), only from the pre-parsed structures (`RSAParameters`, `DSAParameters`, `ECParameters`).

The easiest way to accomplish this goal on Linux (if BouncyCastle can't help you out) is to use `System.Process` to spawn a call similar to `openssl pkcs12 -export -out tmp.pfx -in tmp.cer -inkey tmp.key -password pass:""`.

On Windows you could maybe use CngKey.Import and P/Invoke [CertSetCertificateContextProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376573(v=vs.85).aspx) (for CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE_PROP_ID (78)) to then call `cert.Export` on the mutated certificate.

---

**Update (2020-09-30):** With .NET 3.0 this is reasonably straightforward (doesn't answer the original question of "with .NET Standard", since it requires compiling for netcoreapp3.0 or higher), and it's easy to also add support for PEM-encoded keys with .NET 5.0.

This code checks to see if the key file is PEM encoded (instead of binary/DER encoded), using the .NET 5.0 `PemEncoding` class, then loads the private key using supported formats, matches the private key up to the certificate, then exports.  The key import methods were all added in .NET Core 3.0.

```
private enum KeyFileKinds
{
    None = 0,
    Pkcs8,
    EncryptedPkcs8,
    RsaPrivateKey,
    Any = -1,
}

public static byte[] MakePfx(string certPath, string keyPath, string exportPassword)
{
    using X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
    byte[] keyBytes;
    KeyFileKinds kinds;
    ReadOnlySpan<char> keyFileText = File.ReadAllText(keyPath).AsSpan();

    // PemEncoding.TryFind requires net5.0+
    if (PemEncoding.TryFind(keyFileText, out PemFields pemFields))
    {
        keyBytes = new byte[pemFields.DecodedDataLength];

        if (!Convert.TryFromBase64Chars(keyFileText[pemFields.Base64Data], keyBytes, out int written) ||
            written != keyBytes.Length)
        {
            Debug.Fail("PemEncoding.TryFind and Convert.TryFromBase64Chars disagree on Base64 encoding");
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        ReadOnlySpan<char> label = keyFileText[pemFields.Label];

        if (label.SequenceEqual("PRIVATE KEY"))
        {
            kinds = KeyFileKinds.Pkcs8;
        }
        else if (label.SequenceEqual("ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY"))
        {
            kinds = KeyFileKinds.EncryptedPkcs8;
        }
        else if (label.SequenceEqual("RSA PRIVATE KEY"))
        {
            kinds = KeyFileKinds.RsaPrivateKey;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The PEM file type '{label.ToString()}' is not supported.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        kinds = KeyFileKinds.Any;
        keyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(keyPath);
    }

    RSA rsa = null;
    ECDsa ecdsa = null;
    DSA dsa = null;

    switch (cert.GetKeyAlgorithm())
    {
        case "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1":
            rsa = RSA.Create();
            break;
        case "1.2.840.10045.2.1":
            ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
            break;
        case "1.2.840.10040.4.1":
            dsa = DSA.Create();
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The certificate key algorithm '{cert.GetKeyAlgorithm()}' is unknown");
    }

    AsymmetricAlgorithm anyAlg = rsa ?? ecdsa ?? (AsymmetricAlgorithm)dsa;
    bool loaded = false;
    int bytesRead;

    using (rsa)
    using (ecdsa)
    using (dsa)
    {
        if (!loaded && rsa != null && kinds.HasFlag(KeyFileKinds.RsaPrivateKey))
        {
            try
            {
                rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(keyBytes, out bytesRead);
                loaded = bytesRead == keyBytes.Length;
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
            }
        }

        if (!loaded && kinds.HasFlag(KeyFileKinds.Pkcs8))
        {
            try
            {
                anyAlg.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(keyBytes, out bytesRead);
                loaded = bytesRead == keyBytes.Length;
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
            }
        }

        if (!loaded && kinds.HasFlag(KeyFileKinds.EncryptedPkcs8))
        {
            try
            {
                // This assumes that the private key was already exported
                // with the same password that the PFX will be exported with.
                // Not true? Add a parameter :).
                anyAlg.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(exportPassword, keyBytes, out bytesRead);
                loaded = bytesRead == keyBytes.Length;
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
            }
        }

        if (!loaded)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not load the key as any known format.");
        }

        X509Certificate2 withKey;

        if (rsa != null)
        {
            withKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
        }
        else if (ecdsa != null)
        {
            withKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(ecdsa);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Assert(dsa != null);
            withKey = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(dsa);
        }

        using (withKey)
        {
            return withKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, exportPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update (2020-10-09)**: The previous update showed better code from .NET Core 3.1, but then also some looking ahead code from .NET 5.  If the certificate file is in the PEM format (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICIATE-----`) and the key file is in a PEM format (BEGIN PRIVATE KEY / BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY / BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY / BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY) then there's an even simpler approach with .NET 5:

```
using (X509Certificate2 certWithKey = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certPath, keyPath))
{
    return certWithKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, exportPassword);
}
```

Also available as `CreateFromPem(loadedCertPem, loadedKeyPem)`, `CreateFromEncryptedPem(loadedCertPem, loadedKeyPem, keyPassword)`, and `CreateFromEncryptedPemFile(certPath, keyPath, keyPassword)`.

Comment: PFX/PKCS#12 is a lot more than concatenating certificates and keys.

Comment: @jww true, but `cert.Export` (to a PFX) takes care of it once you can get the key associated

Comment: @bartonjs Could you provide an example of how to do that with BouncyCastle, please?

Comment: @Maxim Nope, I've never used BouncyCastle, merely know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core 3.1 (it's missing PEM methods), I used this logic:

```
var privateKeyLines = File.ReadAllText(keyPath)
    .Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(x => !(x.StartsWith("--") && x.EndsWith("--")));
var privateKey = string.Join("", privateKeyLines);
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);

    using (X509Certificate2 publicCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath))
    using (X509Certificate2 publicAndPrivateCombinedCertificate = publicCertificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa))
    {
        return publicAndPrivateCombinedCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
    }
}
```

It returns byte[], which you can use in the X509Certificate2 constructor.